# biblatex-philosophy can't handle relatedtype

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-philosophy

With `biblatex-philosophy` as option passed to `biblatex` and `german` as main language everything is fine -- as long as biblatex doesn't encounter `relatedtype = {reprint}` or `= {reprintin}`. It inserts the `translationas`-string, which is totally out of place.

If `hyphenation = {german}`, here in the first two entries, it prints "übers. als" (`translatedas`-string), if `hyphenation = {english}`, next two entries, it first prints the `reprint`-string, then the `translationas`-string, probably taken from `german.lbx`. If `translationas` isn't defined at all, it only prints **translationas** in bold.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[main=ngerman,german,italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes,hyperref}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern,sortlocale=auto,sorting=nyvt,
            backend=biber,autolang=hyphen]{biblatex}
\makeatletter
\begin{filecontents*}{reprintbib.bib}
@Article{Bruns:Attische,
      author =   {Ivo Bruns},
       title =   {Attische Liebestheorien etc.},
  hyphenation=   {german},
journaltitle = {Neue Jahrb{\"{u}}cher etc.},
       year =    1900,
     volume =    3,
      pages =    {17-37},
    related =    {Bruns:Attische2},
relatedtype =    {reprintin}
}

 @InBook{Bruns:Attische2,
      options =      {skipbib},
        title =      {Attische Liebestheorien},
   hyphenation=      {german},
          year =     1905,
       author =      {Ivo Bruns},
    booktitle =      {Vortr{\"{a}}ge und Aufs{\"{a}}tze},
    bookauthor =     {Ivo Bruns},
     publisher =     {Beck'sche Verlagsbuchhandlung},
      location =     {N{\"{o}}rdlingen},
       chapter =     6,
         pages =     {118-53}
}

  @Article{Burkert:Ursprung,
      author =   {Walter Burkert},
       title =   {Platon oder Pythagoras?},
  hyphenation=   {english},
  journaltitle = {Hermes},
         year =  1960,
       volume =  88,
        pages =  {159-77},
     related =   {Burkert:Schriften3},
     relatedtype =  {reprint}
}

@Book{Burkert:Schriften3,
  author =   {Walter Burkert},
  gender =   {sm},
  options=   {dataonly},
  title =    {Mystica, Orphica, Pythagorica},
  hyhenation = {english},
  year =     2006,
 editor =    {Fritz Graf},
maintitle =  {Kleine Schriften},
  volume =   3,
publisher =  {Vandenhoeck {\&} Ruprecht},
 location =  {G{\"{o}}ttingen},
  chapter =  14,
   pages =   {217-35}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\makeatother
\addbibresource{reprintbib.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Bruns, Ivo

1900 „Attische Liebestheorien etc.“ Neue Jahrbücher etc., 3, S. 17–37;
übers. als [*should be* Nachdr. als]„Attische Liebestheorien“, in Vorträge und Aufsätze,
Beck’sche Verlagsbuchhandlung, Nördlingen 1905, Kap. 6, S. 118–
53.

Burkert, Walter
1960 „Platon oder Pythagoras?“, Hermes, 88, S. 159–77; Nachdr. übers.
als [*should be* Nachdr. in *only*]Kleine Schriften, Bd. 3: Mystica, Orphica, Pythagorica, hrsg.
von Fritz Graf, Vandenhoeck & Ruprecht, Göttingen 2006, Kap. 14,
S. 217–35.

Comment: Mhh what exactly would you like to see? "Nachdr." in both cases?

Comment: Yes, *only* "Nachdr." or "Nachdr. in" or "Nachdr. von", there is no translation here. I don't understand why it uses the `translationas`-string.

Comment: Yes, I have found the code that inserts the `translationas` string. (Are you sure you need `reprintin` in your first example, don't you just want `reprint`?)

Comment: If reprint does it, it's enough. I used it to test/show its behavior and because the essay is only a chapter in the collection where it is reprinted.

Comment: I have no clue about your sources, I just thought from the quick glance I threw at them that maybe the `relatedtype`s just be the other way round.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The German language files are missing a translation for `reprintin`, so that is the first thing we need to provide

```
\NewBibliographyString{reprintin}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  reprintin       =  {Nachdr. in}}
```

If the `relatedtype` string is not known it is not printed (there is no bold key that warns you of that).

But then `biblatex-philsophy` automatically prints `translationas` if no `relatedstring` is present. You can turn that off with

```
\renewbibmacro*{related:default}[1]{%
  \togglefalse{cbx:scauthorscite}%
  \togglefalse{bbx:annotation}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{%horrible trick
    \renewcommand*{\mkpureparens}{\unspace\addsemicolon\space}%
    \renewcommand*{\mkbibbrackets}{\unspace\addsemicolon\space}}%
  \relatedcite{\thefield{related}}}
```

and (sorry, it's long)

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \renewbibmacro*{related:default}[1]{%
    \togglefalse{cbx:scauthorscite}%
    \togglefalse{bbx:annotation}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \relatedcite{\thefield{related}}}%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:inbeforejournal}{\usebibmacro{in:}}{}%
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{issn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate:article-inbook-incoll}%MOD
  \newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\ifdefstring{\bbx@relatedformat}{semicolon}{\setunit{\addsemicolon\space}}%
    {\setunit{\unspace\space}}%horrible trick
    \usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}%
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

---

The [`biblatex-philosophy` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-philosophy/biblatex-philosophy.pdf) mentions this behaviour only in passing

> The related entry is preceded by the translationas string which defaults to “trad. it.” for Italian documents and “trans. as” for English documents. If you want to change it, use the `relatedstring` field.

So the "official" `biblatex-philsophy` way would be to give the `relatedtype` as `relatedstring` and it works that way, too.

```
@Article{Bruns:Attische,
  author        = {Ivo Bruns},
  title         = {Attische Liebestheorien etc.},
  hyphenation   = {german},
  journaltitle  = {Neue Jahrb{\"{u}}cher etc.},
  year          = 1900,
  volume        = 3,
  pages         = {17-37},
  related       = {Bruns:Attische2},
  relatedstring = {reprintin},
}
```

Of course it would be slightly nicer if `relatedtype` worked, since with `relatedstring` we only control the introductory string, while `relatedtype` allows for fine-grained control over the output.

Comment: hm, the strings in `german.lbx` were empty (`% FIXME: missing`), so I uncommented them and wrote own definitions -- then, I expected it to work. I also had a look into the `english-philosophy.lbx`, which doesn't add anything to the problem. The thing ist, it prints the `translationas`-string notwithstanding that there is no translation of anything, even if I declare english the main language. So, why aren't there any relations other than translations? I can't imagine that anybody imposes such restrictions on a *bibliography*.

Comment: @AlexanderWittmann As I wrote above, `biblatex-philsophy` in a way "defaults" to `translatedas`. You can either use the two lengthy blocks of code I suggested above, or you use `relatedstring` instead of `relatedtype`. If that doesn't work for you, please show a full minimal example of how it doesn't work for you.

Comment: The reason is: My `.bib`-files have to be totally independent from this capricious bib-style. You don't rewrite the bible because your priest can't pronounce certain words. So I'll use your code block and hope that it is willing to cooperate with a former code I got from here: several `related`-items reprinted together.

Comment: @AlexanderWittmann Agreed, using `relatadestring` is more of a work-around than a solution. I think it is not unreasonable to ask the author of the package about that. You don't want to carry around my fix in all your documents.